# What tools can I use to draw a battle map?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, map-making, worldbuilding-resources

I want to draw a battle map for the cover of my book.

By *battle map* I mean an image like this:

[image: Sample battle map]

What tools can I use in order to draw such map easily?

Comment: This is open ended because many different tools can be used easily. How will you decide which answer to accept?

Comment: Here are some good recommendations:  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/395/drawing-software-for-amateurs

Comment: Pencil, ink, and paper?

Comment: @DustinJackson I'm looking for a tool with prepackaged assets (arrows, landscape symbols etc.), which I can re-use legally in my map. I don't need anything fancy, it's enough that the reader looks at the image and thinks - ah, this is a battle!

Comment: @DustinJackson Also, the tool I'm looking for should work for people, who cannot draw. I cannot draw. And if I do, I usually draw straight lines in 90 and 45 degrees angle. So pencil, ink and paper won't work for me. :)

Comment: Do you have the map planned out already? If not, you could modify an existing topographical map from the United States Geological Survey. They are public domain and [free to download](http://nationalmap.gov/ustopo/index.html), so you can reuse them legally, and they are probably more detailed than you would be able to make on your own.

Comment: I believe the hardest part would be to draw the landscape, not to place arrows and army simbols (infantry, cavalry, artillery etc). I believe something based on the voronoi algorithmn can do, but i have no time to write a program like that that. Its not exactly the hardest thing to write. Regarding a software already done to provide this, i believe it does not exists yet.

Comment: You might check on the TeX site http://tex.stackexchange.com/ to see if there's an existing package to do this.  It wouldn't be difficult (for someone used to programming) to do it with Tikz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have (or are too cheap to spend) the dinero for the optimal solution, which is the [Creative Cloud](http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html) (Photoshop, Illustrator) suite of editors, you could generally use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/), as it is free, and being vector-based (so editable), it produces images that scale better and are more controllable than those directly from [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/). This is made in Inkscape in about 5 minutes, eyeballing your sample map:

[image: 5minutes]

However, others [swear by GIMP](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=1142), so your mileage might vary. Probably you could use them in combination.

You can get [fancy stuff](http://www.cartographersguild.com/feature/) out of (free) Inkscape (+GIMP):
[image]

Comment: +1 Holy Smokes! That top one only took you 5 minutes 'eye-balling'?

Comment: I drew maps by hand as a kid by looking at an atlas, so I'm decent at eye-balling, but this Inkscape stuff does not really take any dexterity: you can edit stuff after you draw it. Plus you can use layers if you want.

Comment: Are you a member of the Cartographer's Guild?

Comment: Lurker. Are you?

Comment: Inkscape is truly amazing for quickly producing this kind of diagrams

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest way would be GIMP or Photoshop. GIMP is free.

Here is a 5 minute work example, with a computer mouse not a drawing tablet.

[image]

The arrows are ugly as hell, but you can use plugins like this one:

http://www.maketecheasier.com/draw-arrows-in-gimp/

Another solution is Inkscape (https://inkscape.org)

Here is an example what you can do with it (not by me obiously). 
[image link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Battle_of_Waterloo.svg)

Comment: Could you back that up, perhaps by showing a battle map of yours or link to someone else's published version, made using The GIMP? Even better if you explain how long it took! Unfortunately I think it is likely that expertise with a drawing tool makes things "easy" using it, compared to different tools. I might use The GIMP for this task too . . . but only because I have spent many hours in it.

Comment: I never used it for that, I just know you can. To make the brown and green smudges you can just use the standard paint brush tool. The black lines you can draw with the pencil tool. I don't know for sure but I am pretty certain the programs have standard forms for arrow to make, and even if not you can easily make those in paint and import them. If you have 0 experience with painting programs I'd reckon it takes you an hour or two to make something like this. Just use a tutorial here and there.

Comment: I think you are looking for a drag and drop solution but I don't think if this exists, and if it does chances are you'll have to pay for it. But if you do find a free one, tell me here :p

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This really needs more detail to be a complete answer

Comment: The questions was a tool, I gave a tool. But I shall clarify it nonetheless.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I feel like there is nothing else to explain. The map in the question is very simple : It uses a font, a combination of rectangles, lines and some random shapes. In that regard, Gimp or even Paint could do the job, but paint has just one layer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the Inksape link until after I answered...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a vector program like Inkscape or illustrator since you can select and move the different elements at all time. Or you can use a raster program like Gimp, Paint or Photoshop but each time you modify a shape, you risk losing some pixels.

- You start by making the symbols you will use often. Like the rectangle
  below the names and the arrows. The program should have shapes
  somewhere to make rectangles, triangles or arrows. The shortcut is U
  in Photoshop. Make a copy of the symbols and duplicate them
  (duplicate the layer or use the duplicate tool: S) each time you add
  one on the map.
- For the colored shapes (landmass and forests): use the pen:B and draw the exterior of the zone. To save time, you can bucket fill the interior of the zone with the bucket: G or you can color it manually.
- Roads.: Use the pen with black or ideally a dark brown with a small
  radius. Do the same thing for the rivers but in blue and with a
  larger pen.
- The building: made with rectangles that are empty or used white in
  the interior. Stack some rectangles and when the building is ok, rotate it as you wish.
- Labels, use a font that is easy to read like that one. Arial or Helvetica will do the job. You can rotate
  it but do so before pixelating the text.

I think that's all. Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a professional map creation tool like [ProFantasy](https://www.profantasy.com/). You would have to buy it. You can see that the final quality is good and may be worth the purchase.

There are a lot of symbol sets as add-ons you can find [here](https://secure.profantasy.com/products/add-ons.asp#symbolsets).

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Rod*! What are the main advantages of that tool? Is it free or does it cost money and if so, how much would one probably have to pay to use this tool? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to http://mashupforge.com is a web tool to make and share maps. It is very versatile and easy to use **but it isn't exactly what you are searching for** (although it can be used for that).

If you want to use your own icons or background layers, you can upload your images. To make this I recommend to use a vector based drawing tool like Inkscape to draw your stuff.

For example in 3 minutes I was [able to create this](http://mashupforge.com/8493/4MQRTQ/) but you can make maps like this [Skyrim map](http://mashupforge.com/582/AQOfHyq4Omzp0fEfFIN70sy9yp9X8K/).

Answer (score 1):

When I came across this question, I thought of Inkscape too.

Battlegames magazine (as it used to be known) issue 13 had an article on using it for just this type of thing, which is now available online as a PDF.

It's a tutorial based article for people new to Inkscape and digital map making. I have worked through this article myself for simple maps.

http://kriegsspiel.homestead.com/files/Accessories/BG13-computer_cartography.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I really like paint.net 
It's free. And it's like paint (super easy to use) but with layers and transparency. Actually it's kind of a cross between photoshop and paint.

[>> paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tanasa's excellent recommendations, you can also use AutoREALM if you're on Windows (or through WinE for Linux). This is their SourceForge [site.](http://autorealm.sourceforge.net/)